# github: how to see latest commits including from all its forks?

Tags: git, github

Is there a button or script to see latest commits including from all its forks?

Because sometime I want to see if there are some useful related commits to be merged in.

Comment: On github there is a `network` graph, but the interface is too hard to see when there are many forks.

Comment: Network is nowadays not so bad. ex: https://github.com/mawburn/portaler-core/network

Answer (score 0):

You have it in [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).

Set the view to display all your branches and then you can see all the commits from all your branches.

[image]

Its exactly what you asked for :-)

Comment: Thank you for the introduce of the nice tool. But it seems focus on one repository, but cannot gather information from all the forked repositories.

Comment: You cant use it on multiple repositories. Im not aware on any tool which can combine multiple repositories

Answer (score 0):

To View the Commit History
Type **git log**

For commit history Further Reference
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

To verify the new upstream repository you've specified for your fork . 
Type **git remote -v**

For Fork Further Reference
https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/topics/forks contains a few repos that proclaim to help with that task.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub interface has changed a couple of times this last years.
As mentioned in a comment, there is the **Network** graph, accessible from the interface.

Click on **Fork** (top right), then find the link **View existing forks**.

Here first clue: if a fork has itself forks, maybe it's active and more advanced than the current one.

Click on **Network** (in the left menu), a diagram should display  the activity of other forks under the current one. If the activity is more on the right, then it's more advanced.

[image]